# How do I upgrade my Debezium plug-in version in Kafka connect?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am currently running Debezium 0.9.4 and I want to upgrade it to the latest version 1.6. Do I simply download the jar files and save them to the plug-in directory specified in my kafka-connect `worker.properties` file? From the document [here](https://debezium.io/releases/1.6/release-notes#upgrading), what do they mean by

```
remove the old plugin files, install the 1.6.0.CR1 plugin files
```

What is the CR1 plug-in files? Where are the JAR files?

Comment: old plugin files - refers to the current version that you are upgrading from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Release 1.6.0.CR1 (June 24th, 2021)   is the name of release and according to the docs, yes, you stop the connector gracefully,  remove the old JARs (from the directory that you currently have) and copy the new ones. Good luck!

Move the current content of {/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins/debezium-connector-mysql/} to a backup folder outside of {/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins} and copy the unziped directory into the plugin path

You might want to reconsider as according to the release page 1.5 is the current stable release , looking on their release cycle next month probably would came out 1.6 final as stable version.

https://debezium.io/releases/

> When you decide to upgrade one of these connectors to 1.6.0.CR1 from any earlier versions, first check the migration notes for the version you’re using. Gracefully stop the running connector, remove the old plugin files, install the 1.6.0.CR1 plugin files, and restart the connector using the same configuration. Upon restart, the 1.6.0.CR1 connectors will continue where the previous connector left off. As one might expect, all change events previously written to Kafka by the old connector will not be modified

Comment: thanks for the tip @Ran Lupovich, so I went to download the MySQL Connector plug-in zip file from here https://debezium.io/releases/1.5/ Do I take the contents and place them in the plug-in path `/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins/debezium-connector-mysql/`? Currently i see `antlr4-runtime-4.7.jar` `debezium-connector-mysql-0.9.4-SNAPSHOT.jar` `debezium-core-0.9.4-SNAPSHOT.jar` `debezium-ddl-parser-0.9.3.Final.jar` `mysql-binlog-connector-java-0.19.0.jar` `mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar` and `protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar`. I just need to overwrite these guys with the updated JARS right?

Comment: Move the current content of {/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins/debezium-connector-mysql/} to a backup folder outside of {/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins} and copy the unziped file into the plugin path

Comment: thank you! Hopefully this is as straight-forward as it gets!

Comment: hey @Ran Lupovich, I might have messed something up. I paused all the debezium connectors, updated all the JAR files in the plug-in directory, and restarted the connector and kafka-connect service but I am now seeing these errors `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only a single connector task may be started` in my logs. I tried googling this error message but cannot seem to find much related to it